# Lost OS X Java source code

Tags: java, macos

I upgraded to JDK 6 build 22 on Snow Leopard and now I cannot find the src.zip file. I downloaded `javadeveloper_10.6_10m3261` from the Apple Developer's website and installed it, but a `find . -name src.zip -ls` in both /System and /Developer yields nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This thread should be of interest: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Java-dev/2010/Oct/msg00302.html